# React cant re-render While button click

Tags: reactjs, closures, rerender

[image]

I am trying to make 4 cards with buttons and when ı click a button ı wanna change the background colour of the button. But at the first click, it is working after that it's not rendering buttons. How can I handle it?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as image.

Answer (score 2):

On the line 9 you are mutating state, you should update state only with setter function

Answer (score 0):

In your code on line 9 your are mutating the state like this >

```
state[index]={active: demo}
```

Instead of this use setState function to update state. Using setState  will re-
render your state.
you can do something like this

```
let arr = {}
arr = {active: demo}
setState(arr)
```

Comment: But I would like to choose a button in each card at the same time

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues present in your code

First: On line number 9 you are mutating state, you should update state using setstate function.

```
setstate(prevState => {
    const newState = [...prevState];
    newState[index] = { active: deneme };
    return newState;
})
```

Second: On line number 21 you have to include the special attribute "key" on "Collapsible" component.

```
<Collapsible key={item.toString()} trigger-"Start here" contentContainerTagName="div">
```

[react list keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)